# Identifying updated models in Peewee

Tags: python, database, peewee

Let's assume the following Peewee model:

```
class TestModel(Model):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = CharField()
    text = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

If we have a populated database with instances of this model, and select them all, we get the following results:

```
>>> old_models = [m for m in TestModel.select()]
>>> # old_models contains two TestModels stored in DB: 
>>> # TestModel(id=1, name='red', text='hello')
>>> # TestModel(id=5, name='blue', text='world')
```

Now, from an external source, we get a list of data that we convert into our models:

```
>>> new_models = []
>>> new_models.append(TestModel(id=1, name='red', text='hello'))
>>> new_models.append(TestModel(id=5, name='red', text='NOT WORLD'))
>>> new_models.append(TestModel(id=10, name='green', text='hello world'))
```

Getting newly-added models (i.e. not present in the DB) and those that have been added is easy:

```
>>> added_models = [m for m in new_models if m not in old_models]
>>> # added_models with contain TestModel with ID 10
```

What's the most efficient way to find those models that have been updated though? In our case, the model with ID 5. Overwriting the existing models with the newly-retrieved data won't work because a dirty field is every field that is touched. And even if we overwrite a value if it does not equal, then we lose the ability to compare both values (new and old). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do this with the Model API, but there is a way to do it if you are willing to depend on an implementation detail of peewee Models.  Also it probably won't be very fast at scale.

There is a dict representing the Model's data in `m.__dict__['_data']` that you can use.

First, get a `dict` of `old_models` by id:

```
old_models_by_id = {m.get_id(): m for m in old_models}
```

Then, write a simple function comparing two Model's data

```
def compare_models(m1, m2):
    """Return True if two models have exactly the same data"""
    return m1.__dict__['_data'] == m2.__dict__['_data']
```

Finally, get updated models:

```
updated_models = [m for m in updated_models 
                  if m.get_id() in old_models_by_id 
                  and not compare_models(m, old_models_by_id.get(m.get_id()))]
```

Answer (score 0):

building upun @thaavik's answer-
in modern peewee (im using 3.13) the dict name was changed to `__data__`
so you need to use `m1.__dict__['__data__']`

somthing else you can do is use `dict`'s `.items()` method and the ^ operator (Exclusive Or) to get the difference between the two item sets

```
a = {"a": 1, "c": 1}
b=  {"b": 1, "c":2}
print(a.items()^ b.items())
> {('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 1), ('b', 1)}
```